# make_array with compound type not working

Tags: c++

```
#include <array>

template<typename... T>
static inline constexpr std::array<typename std::common_type<T...>::type, sizeof...(T)>
make_array(T &&...t)
{
        return {std::forward<T>(t)...};
}

struct foo {
        int x, y;
};

int main()
{
        auto a1 = make_array<int>(1,2,3); // OK
        auto a2 = make_array<foo>({1,2},{3,4}); //  error: too many arguments to function ...
        auto a2 = make_array<foo>(foo{1,2}, foo{3,4}); // OK when explicitly specifying type
}
```

I would like to use `make_array` without specifying the type of each element, is this possible?

Comment: I **think** if you don't use `std::common_type` or such, and instead insist upon a single known type for each element, then no deduction is required from the braced-init-lists, and it can work. I need to check whether I use this somewhere though as I can't quite remember.

Comment: @underscore_d Then you would need to specify the size as well.

Comment: @underscore_d, That question deals with deducing types from a braced init list. This question specifies the pack's type arguments explicitly. (However, it might not be the pack that was actually desired.) It's fundamentally the same issue, but the explanation for why doesn't suffice for this question's context.

Comment: @underscore_d already tried that too.
seems it isn't possible, and I guess that why std::to_array was created.

Answer (score 2):

If you're fine with passing all the arguments through a braced initializer list like this:

```
auto a1 = make_array<int>({1,2,3}); 
auto a2 = make_array<foo>({{1,2},{3,4}}); 
auto a3 = make_array<foo>({foo{1,2}, foo{3,4}});
```

then you can pretend it's a fixed-size array and write this:

```
template<typename T, std::size_t N>
static constexpr auto make_array(T const (&a)[N])
{
    std::array<T, N> res;
    std::copy(a, a + N, std::begin(res));
    return res; 
}
```

Here's a [demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e96bbv).

Comment: I like the answer for your out-of-bounds thinking, and it actually works for the example I gave.

But it is not generic, it will break more complex types, therefore I won't accept your answer, sorry.

Comment: @HerrTeetrinken Sure. Could you update the question to show an example of where this doesn't work?